# Set fixed position for selected li on horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a horizontal scroll with "selected" li class changing based on the user scroll. What I am trying to do is to make the selected li in a fixed position as it disappears after scrolling for a while.

My code:

```
<div id="scroller2">
<ul id="ulscroller">
<li value="01" class="selected">1<div class="li-image"><img src="img/icon-dark.png" style="float: left;"></div></li>
<li value="02">2<div class="li-image"><img src="img/icon-dark.png" style="float: left;"></div></li>
...

<li value="30">30<div class="li-image"><img src="img/icon-dark.png" style="float: left;"></div></li>

</ul>

</div>

var scroller2 = document.getElementById("scroller2"),
    lis = scroller2.getElementsByTagName("li"),
    divisionsWidth2 = lis[0].offsetWidth - 20,
    current = 0
    scroller2.onscroll = function(){
    var selected = Math.floor(scroller2.scrollLeft/divisionsWidth2);
    if (current!==selected) {
        lis[current].className="";
        lis[selected].className="selected";
        current = selected;

        $("#nono2").html(lis[current].value);
    }
};
```

Please check out Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7uCS8/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep something visibly selected on the screen at all times, you can change the `divisionsWidth2` that you use to calculate which element is selected to use the average width of the li items instead of only using the *first* one: http://jsfiddle.net/7uCS8/2/

```
avewidth = 0;
$("li").each(function () {
   avewidth += $(this).get(0).offsetWidth; 
});
avewidth = parseInt(avewidth / $("li").length);
```

It would look even better if all of the `li`s were equal width; not sure how difficult that would be for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, gives the same behavior for me.

Comment: @ManMann it may depend on how wide the window is; you'll have to keep tweaking to get the width you want.  I don't think it's `- 20`, but some percentage of the `#scroller2` width.

Comment: the problem is that i am using this code on a web application where the window width may differ so i am afraid that am in the wrong path using my code.